# How to beautify comments in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, plugins, styles, comments, readability

I'm looking for a way (a plugin, or a macro) to style my comments for readability.

For example, I want function names at the closing parantheses like :

```
function f()
{
 bla=bla;
 longcode=longcode;
}// function f()
```

or long and flashy comments like this :

```
/* ----------------------------------------------
   -----  here starts the database functions ----
   ---------------------------------------------- */
```

Are there plugins or any other ways to do this quickly ?

Thanks for any help !

### edit:

I mean I want to write `here starts the database functions` and with a key combo or something, the plugin should convert it to the beautified version.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Language menu at the top to define what you're coding in. It should then color code correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking for automatic comment out and dashes, not color.